# Move images from service and update paths in forum

Tags: mysql, regex, shell

I run a popular forum where one of the members who has made a lot of awesome contributions recently contacted us.  He has posted several hundred images from his webshots gallery, but the service is changing as are all the images.  I need to change all the image src paths in all of his posts in our mysql database.

He was given the opportunity to download all the images which he has given to me.  Because I will be having to do a lot of these changes in production I need to make sure that I don't screw this up.

The image src in his posts look similar to this, where 0103935217 I believe is his user ID.

```
http://inlinethumb25.webshots.com/47576/2156388770103935217S500x500Q85.jpg
```

The images downloaded from the service look like this.  Notice the S500x500Q85 has been replaced with a random string.

```
2156388770103935217Reacil_fs.jpg
```

So I have two tasks:

1. I need to rename the all the files I've put on my server removing the random characters and the _fs designation.
2. I need to change the file paths in all of his posts removing domain and container and replacing it with mine.  In addition I need to remove the S500x500Q85 designation.

For 1. I have a regex but I'm unsure how to do the replacement 0103935217\w+?_fs

For 2. I know my query needs to be something along the lines of the below.  I'm a little unsure how to do this though, is it with a regex?

```
UPDATE posts SET post_body = replace(post_body, '','') WHERE user_id = 1234
```

Comment: I would do this in a script, rather than in straight SQL.  Grab all of his posts LIKE '%webshots.com%', process them with the logic you've outlined, and then update the records with the altered content.

Comment: I thought about doing that.  I also suppose I could run two queries, one to change the domain and path, and another to remove the postfix.  Since I'm replacing the alter with nothing a regex shouldn't be required and I could just do replace(post_body, 'S500x500Q85','')

Comment: You could probably still do it all in one query, like `replace(replace(post_body, 'http://inlinethumb25.webshots.com/47576/', '<your URL>'), 'S500x500Q85', '')`